# Rewrite rule in htaccess mapping to wrong url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue on this. Say, I have `mypage.com/search/mykey` and i want it to map to `mypage.com/search?key=mykey`. This is my .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /search?key=$1 [L]


# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

However, in the logs I can see that it's mapping to `mypage.com/search/mykey?key=mykey`.

Edit:
To give more context on what can be the issue, I included the rewrite rule just below the one I wrote. Don't know if they're messing each other.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: I have MultiViews disabled, and, I do not need a search directory becasue it is supposed to be processed later by the index.php file since it's a "pretty url"

Comment: ok in that case inside your index.php you will get `REQUEST_URI=/search/mykey` with `QUERY_STRING` as `key=mykey`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: "in the logs" - what "logs"?

Comment: In the apache logs. To be clear, what I want is to navigate to /search/term, and BEHIND the scenes, without the user knowing, make the index.php process /search?key=term. So far, I haven't been able to get it, because it always maps to /search/term?key=term instead but I need to remove the `/term` from the processed url

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `RewriteBase "/"` in that way apache knows that relative files must be within the rewrite base path.

```
RewriteBase "/"
...
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search?key=$1 [L]
...
```

- Note: RewriteBase affects all relative files named in rewrite rules